# Can you go skiing on a trip to Warsaw in late December?

Tags: poland, winter, skiing

I am going to be in Warsaw during the last week of December with two kids (8, 12).

- Is it possible to go skiing that time of year in Warsaw region? (both natural and man made snow are fine)
- Is there a place we can go skiing for a couple of days? The place has be suitable for beginners and be within two hours or so drive from Warsaw. It could be downhill or cross country - as long as it's suitable for kids with no prior experience.

Any tips and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Not really, the area south of Krakow is the main skiing area http://www.livekrakow.com/activities/the-5-closest-ski-resorts-to-krakow/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can’t really do proper skiing in Warsaw. You are trapped on an endless lowland around Warsaw, you don’t get to see much snow nor hills. To do proper skiing you need to go to Zakopane (8 hours by car/train).

The highest hill near Warsaw is 700 metres at the *Nartraj in Chrzanów* ski resort, but it is 3 hours away.

A Ski Resort within 2 hours is *Ski resort Baba Jaga in Bodzentyn* which is just less than 2 hours away. It has 3 ski lifts, 130 – 650 m.

The closest Ski Resort is *Gorka Szczesliwicka* which is 15 minutes from the centre of Warsaw. It is 152 meters high artificial hill in the center of Warsaw. Probably the best possible option if you hate going out of town but still want to ski.

[This article](https://planpoland.com/cross-country-skiing-in-warsaw/) provides information on where and how to go cross country skiing in Warsaw but choice is very limited.